# case in bash: "line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `)'"

Tags: linux, bash, syntax-error, case

case in bash:

> line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

I'm trying to use the command `case` in Bash (on my Raspberry Pi again), but when I run my script, Bash spits out errors.  I've read over many tutorials and I think I'm doing the same thing as them, but something's just not right.

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
        help) echo "You asked for help. Sorry, I'm busy."
        *) echo "You didn't say anything. Try 'help' as the first argument."
esac
```

Here's the output (the filename is newmkdir and I ran it with no arguments):

```
./newmkdir: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./newmkdir: line 4: `   *) echo "You didn't say anything. Try 'help' as the first argument."'
```

I'm trying to have my script interpret `help` and then make anything else output the next line.

(Note this is just an example of a glitched script.  This script has no meaning and might not even make sense, it's just a test.)

Comment: You need `;;` in each cases.

Comment: You may find [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing `;;` at the end of each pattern:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
        help)
            echo "You asked for help. Sorry, I'm busy."
            ;;
        *)
            echo "You didn't say anything. Try 'help' as the first argument."
            ;;
esac
```

Think of it as a `break` statement in a programming language. They are compulsory on `case`.

Comment: Technically, the `;;` is optional before the `esac`, but that's a bad reason for leaving it off.

Comment: Thanks!  ... I realized the tabbing 'issue' right after I posted this, but thanks anyway for correcting it.